# How to query a reference in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have found this tutorial online which is helpful.  However it shows an example using an array of two objectIds.  How could the query be done if it was one objectId instead of two?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_relationships.htm

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
   "contact": "987654321",
   "dob": "01-01-1991",
   "name": "Tom Benzamin",
   "address_ids": [
      ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000000"), // if this was not an array and just one ObjectId
      ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000001") 
   ]
}

var result = db.users.findOne({"name":"Tom Benzamin"},{"address_ids":1})
var addresses = db.address.find({"_id":{"$in":result["address_ids"]}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got it right. So you have elements of this sort:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
   ...
   "address_ids": ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000000")
}
```

Your code will look like this:

```
var result = db.users.findOne({"name":"Tom Benzamin"},{"address_ids":1})
var addresses = db.address.find({"_id": result["address_ids"]})
```